# Can I change GROUP_CONCAT Limit in SQLite?

Tags: windows, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am thinking about switching from MySQL to SQLite,
but in the MySQL Server I set the variable `group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Before I switch everything to the SQLite engine I want to know if there is a limit too and if I can change it, in case of, can I change the limit with this query?

```
set global group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find such specific limitation in [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

However, there is a max length that surely applies to the result of a group_concat, because [it is defined as the "maximum size of any string or BLOB or table row, in bytes."](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_limit_attached.html). To see and change it, connect the SQLite database and type :

```
sqlite> -- Diplay all limits
sqlite> .limit
              length 1000000000
          sql_length 1000000000
              column 2000
          expr_depth 1000
     compound_select 500
             vdbe_op 250000000
        function_arg 127
            attached 10
 like_pattern_length 50000
     variable_number 32766
       trigger_depth 1000
      worker_threads 0
sqlite> -- Change length limit
sqlite> .limit length 50000
              length 50000
sqlite> -- Display the new length limit
sqlite> .limit length
              length 50000
```

Be careful to keep safe numbers i.e. remain far from [implementation limits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).